# How to pass a variable by prop and not allow child to change it ( vue 2 )

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing a prop to a child component, and coping the prop value to a data() variable. The problem is that when I change the values of data() variable, the values on parent change to, and I dont know why.

So I have a `v-for` on parent where I call the `editar()` method

```
<tr v-for="(mensagem,key) in  allMensagens" :key="key">
  <td class="tipo-mensagem-td">{{mensagem.titulo}}</td>
  <td class="text-center botoes">
   <div class="grupo-botoes">
    <a class="bi bi-pencil-square" role="button" v-on:click="editar(mensagem)" title="Editar Mensagem"></a>
   </div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Then on editar I have this, where the `mensagemEdit` is a `data() variable` on parent component:

```
editar(mensagem)
{
  this.mensagemEdit = mensagem;
  this.toggleCriarMensagem("edit"); 
}
```

Then to show the form to edit I have something like this

```
 <template v-if="criarMensagem">
   <keep-alive>
     <FormAddEditMensagem :mensagemEdit="mensagemEdit" :tipoMensagem="'E'" :acao="acao"/>
   </keep-alive>
 </template>
```

Where I send the mensagemEdit to child, and then on it I have this line of code, where the `mensagem`  is a `data()` var on child:

```
activated() {
    this.mensagem = this.mensagemEdit;
},
```

The problem its that, when I edit the values on this.mensagem, the `mensagemEdit` from parent assume that values, and the mensagem from `v-for`, takes that values, so if I close the form, changing the value of `criarMensagem to false`, I get the not saved, but edited values on table and I dont want that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clone the prop value, with these methods:

1. If the value is a simple data type (string, boolean, number):

```js
this.mensagem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.mensagemEdit));
```

2. If the value is a simple object:

```js
this.mensagem = Object.assign({}, this.mensagemEdit);
```

3. For more complex values (array of objects, nested objects) I suggest using lodash:

```js
import { cloneDeep } from "lodash"

this.mensagem = cloneDeep(this.mensagemEdit);
```

Comment: Second option worked well for me. Thanks :)